# Parallel Processing in R in caret

Tags: r, parallel-processing

It is given in the caret documentation that to allow parallel processing the following code works

```
library(doMC) 
registerDoMC(cores = 5) 
## All subsequent models are then run in parallel
```

But in the latest R version(3.4) the package doMC is not available. Can anyone let me know of any other way to do parallel processing?

Update : What Roman suggested worked. DoMC is not available for windows. For windows use doParallel package `cls = makeCluster(no of cores to use)` and then `registerDoParallel(cls)` . Also make sure allowParallel is set to TRUE in trControl.

Comment: Have you [installed it from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/index.html)?

Comment: I used the R interface to run the install.packages command and it says "This package is not available for R(3.4)" . Is there a way to install it manually from the site?

Comment: If you are on windows, please read [the second paragraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf) of the vignette. On windows, I use `doParallel` package which interfaces to the `parallel` which is shipped with R and loves all platforms equally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`doMC` taps into the power of package `multicore` to calculate in distributed/parallel mode. This is fine, if you're on supported platforms, which Windows isn't.

You can use another framework, like `parallel` which comes shipped with R. To do so, you will need package `doParallel` which works on all three major platforms.

Comment: would you need to set allowParallel= TRUE?

Comment: @Ahdee can you give a bit more context, possibly opening a new question?

Answer (score 8):

Just to expand on the implementation of the previous answers and basically using the [Caret package documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html), here is a recipe that works for me:

```
set.seed(112233)
library(parallel) 
# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

library(doParallel)
# create the cluster for caret to use
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# do your regular caret train calculation enabling
# allowParallel = TRUE for the functions that do
# use it as part of their implementation. This is
# determined by the caret package.

stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually I do it like this adding `allowParallel= TRUE` :

```
svmopt.caret=train(Y~.,data=nearsep1,method="svmLinear",
                   trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=10,search="grid"),
                   tuneGrid=paramgrid,
                   allowParallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: But this works only for the models that internally support parallel processing. Let's say if I use xgboost with allowParallel = TRUE itll work because xgboost has inbuilt parallel processing but if I call let's say random forest it won't work

Comment: @DhruvMahajan that's not true, allowParallel = T does not allow the parallel processing of the underlying model (in this case xgboost). it simply parallelise the cv process, such that each core will perform the train and test of that specific fold of the cv

Comment: seems that `allowParallel=TRUE` should be passed to `trainControl()`, not `train()`. Because this option is in `?trainControl` but not `?train`.

Comment: @Dhruv Mahajan in the case of random forest use parallelization in the `trainControl()` function. Said function is passed as the named parameter `trControl` to **caret**'s `train` method. This cuts down training time substantially when introducing cross-validation for the splitting on variables during the tree growing phase. This is the most time-consuming part of the `rf` ensemble method. Even with all the standardization that **caret** provides there are still minor variations in usage patterns as you rightly suggest.